# how to read $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I've been reading a book on linear algebra. And I wasn't sure how I should read this mathematical expression: $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

Comment: $\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ (*read aloud as "R m by n"*) is a way to notate the set of all matrices with real entries which have $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Comment: @JMoravitz: make your comment as an answer. The OP is exactly want that

Answer (score 0):

It means the set of all matrices of size $m\times n$ with real entries